Ubuntu server 23.04 EOL to 23.10 Unsupported Upgrade Error
I finally got around to upgrading my ubuntu 23.04 lunar server (end of life) to ubuntu 23.10. I'm following these steps https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades. I accidentally installed both upgrade-manager-core and update-manager using
sudo aptitude install update-manager-core update-manager

When following the steps to run the mantic installer,
# Downloads the upgrader, check the link above for the URL of the file for your release
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/focal.tar.gz
# Extract it into a new directory
mkdir upgrader
tar -xaf focal.tar.gz -C upgrader
cd upgrader
# Run the executable, the name changes based on the release
./focal

I'm running into this issue running the upgrader executable:
~/workspace/mantic$ sudo ./mantic

(mantic:20094): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 20:36:34.555: _gtk_css_lookup_resolve: assertion '(((__extension__ ({ GTypeInstance *__inst = (GTypeInstance*) ((provider)); GType __t = ((_gtk_style_provider_private_get_type ())); gboolean __r; if (!__inst) __r = (0); else if (__inst->g_class && __inst->g_class->g_type == __t) __r = (!(0)); else __r = g_type_check_instance_is_a (__inst, __t); __r; }))))' failed
/home/jesse/workspace/mantic/DistUpgrade/SimpleGtk3builderApp.py:33: Warning: g_object_set_data_full: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.builder.add_from_file(path)

(mantic:20094): Gtk-ERROR **: 20:36:34.555: Can't create a GtkStyleContext without a display connection
Trace/breakpoint trap

I tried uninstalling update-manager, but I'm still getting the same error
sudo apt remove upgrade-manager

I'm a ubuntu noob so any help would be appreciated!
Output of lsb_release -a
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:        23.04
Codename:       lunar

Output of do-release-upgrade -d
do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only
available from the latest supported release.


I'm not too sure what you're trying to do.  Can you update your question with the output of lsb_release -a?  If you are still on 23.04, can you try do-release-upgrade -d and see if it is successful?  If not, show us what message you're getting.

Hello @Ray! I updated the post with the outputs of both commands. I am unable to update because 23.04 is EOL and not supported anymore.  Because my ubuntu version is EOL, I have to follow the instructions in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades to upgrade to 23.10. I am stuck on the last step in the doc:

Sorry for the late reply!  Can you describe what happens when you run sudo ./mantic?  Are you connecting to the computer remotely via ssh, etc. or locally as in it is the computer in front of you?  If you have CLI-only system, then yes, you should only install update-manager-core.  But you uninstalled update-manager successfully?  All other commands at that page completed successfully without errors or warnings?

The output of sudo ./mantic is pasted above. No screen is opened and the only thing that happens is the output above. I am ssh'ing into my ubuntu server which is CLI only. I was able to uninstall update-manager without any issues and all other commands on that page completed successfully.
Weirdly enough, the doc states that running sudo ./mantic works the same as do-release-upgrade. When running do-release-upgrade a screen is opened (the ubuntu terminal screen), but the ./mantic executable does not open a screen.

Judging by the error message Can't create a GtkStyleContext without a display connection when running sudo ./mantic, my hunch is that installing update-manager turned my server into a pseduo-desktop. This then requires an actual monitor connected to the machine to run sudo ./mantic. I have not been able to test this as I am currently away from my machine

I have never performed an EOL upgrade.  And yes, the Gtk warnings do indicate that it is opening up a window.  But, personally, I have never heard of installing a program that would change a system into a "pseudo-desktop".  I have looked after desktop Ubuntu machines before and I would ssh into them remotely and run do-release-upgrade on the command-line with no problems.  The whole upgrade was CLI.
Again, this was all before EOL was reached. If you install an X Server on your local computer and ssh -X, you should see the window appear locally.  Perhaps try that?

Any luck @JesseChung ? I have exactly the same problem.

It seems mantic has options, revealed by ./mantic --help. I chose sudo ./mantic --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText.

I left my server alone and gave up for a while. I'll try the above and report back!

Update:
Just ran the above command and that worked for me! I was able to update to mantic and then noble. Thanks for all the help everyone!
